# Assigning to 'void (*)(int)' from incompatible type 'void (Button::*)(int)'

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I'm trying to set a pointer to a member function from another class, but I can't figure out how to do this. I have three classes: Control, Button, Textbox. Button and Textbox have their own void _Draw(), and the Control class has a pointer to void (*drawFunc(int))

I want both Button and Textbox classes having access to Control _drawFunc pointer to set it as their _Draw functions.

```
void Draw1(int t) { 
    printf("%d\n", t);
}

struct Control {
    void (*drawFunc)(int);

    Control() {}
};

struct Button : Control{

    void _Draw(int m) {
        // ... 
    }

    Button() {
        drawFunc = &Button::_Draw; // Draw1 works fine
    }

};

struct Textbox : Control{

    void _Draw(int m) {
        // ... 
    }

    Textbox() {
        drawFunc = &Textbox::_Draw; // Draw1 works fine
    }

};
```

Comment: `void (*drawFunc)(int)` is NOT a pointer-to-member-function. It is a pointer to a regular (freestanding) function. Member functions and regular functions are beasts of completely different nature. You can't make `drawFunc` to point to `Button::_Draw`.

Comment: Pointers to functions and pointers to member functions are different types.

Comment: Also note that names starting with an `_` followed by an `A-Z` are reserved and shouldn't be used.

Comment: ^ Not just shouldn't, mustn't!

Comment: @SJBar -- If you think about this a bit, how would you have made the call to that member function using regular pointer-to-function call syntax?    To call a non-static member function normally, you need an object, i.e. `object.foo()` or `object->foo()`.  So how do you fit `object` into the pointer-to-function call syntax you are familiar with?  That's right, you can't -- different beasts, as stated previously.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `function<void(int)> drawFunc` instead of `void (drawFunc*)(int)` and assign it with `[this](int i) { this->_Draw(m); }` to bind this or you make it static (which does not make sense), but for such problems there are virtual methods:

```
struct Control {
    virtual void draw(int) = 0;

    Control() {};
    virtual ~Control() {};
};

struct Button : public Control {
    void draw(int m) final override { // final is optional: if there are no subclasses of buttons
        // ...
    };
};
```